# Search SQL Server metadata

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to search SQL Server's metadata for all stored procedures that were changed between specific dates.

So far I have following query that looking for specific value in the SP.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sysobjects.name AS [Object Name]
FROM sysobjects,syscomments
WHERE sysobjects.id = syscomments.id
and syscomments.text like '%Stock%'
```

In the example above I am looking for all SP that have word `Stock` in it.

But how can I search for all SP's that were changed between specific dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
AND name = 'uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo'
GO
```

source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/10/sql-server-2005-find-stored-procedure-create-date-and-modified-date/

Comment: I would use `sys.procedures` instead of the generic `sys.objects` - then you don't need to specify the `type = 'P'` - it's clear that you're searching in the procedures....